# registerUserNotificationSettings not showing prompt iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I can't seem to get a prompt to show for `registerUserNotificationSettings` in iOS 8.1 or 8.2.

Here is what I'm doing in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
  if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
       #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert
                                                                                             |UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil];
        NSLog(@"Reg settings %@", settings);
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    #endif
    }
```

Also getting the correct call back here:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings{
    NSLog(@"Did register - %@", notificationSettings);
}
```

Yet no prompt is ever displayed. What's even more annoying is that an alert will display when the device is locked, but won't give the notification alert sound. Any ideas on a work around?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Update for iOS 11+:

Since iOS 11 `Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS` procedure seems not to be necessary anymore. Just un-/reinstall the app.

---

Using your code, I get the prompt on the first app launch, and only on the first launch. But afaik, that's the expected behavior in iOS. 
At least it's the same for photo library, microphone access etc:

#### Permissions Prompt Behavior

1. Popup on first usage (or at least the request to use it)
2. Apple adds an entry in settings (e.g. Privacy, or just under Settings for notifications)

#### First usage

[image: Permissions promt]

#### In the `Settings` App you can configure `Notifications` for each app

1. Scroll down, select your app
2. Select `Notifications`
3. Enable/Disable them, or adjust their behavior

#### Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS

> The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications,
>   iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app.
>   Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again
>   unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at
>   least a day.
>
> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave
>   the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without
>   actually waiting a day by following these steps:
>
> 1. Delete your app from the device.
> 2. Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
> 3. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day
>      or more.
> 4. Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

*Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html*

Comment: So it's normal that if I delete the app and reinstall it, there should not be a prompt?

Comment: I updated my answer with "how to reset the permissions".

Comment: I need to display a custom alert box, instructing the user to go to Settings and turn it on, if the user has already Rejected it previously.  But i can't find a way to make a distinction between the two states:  Notifications were never asked for yet, and Notifications were asked for, but the user already rejected them.

Comment: Maybe this could help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784851/ios-push-notification-settings-denied-permission-vs-permission-never-requested

Answer (score 1):

Change build target latest version you will see the popup message.
Same issue with me in iOS 8 its not showing, but in iOS 10 its showing the alert pop message,  This alert message will be displayed only once for the application cycle. Unless you delete and reinstall new one.

```
- (void)registerLocalNotification{

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still stuck, toggling the options worked for me. It was this

`UNAuthorizationOptions options = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert & UNAuthorizationOptionSound;`

and I changed it to this

`UNAuthorizationOptions options = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert;`

and back to

`UNAuthorizationOptions options = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert & UNAuthorizationOptionSound;`