# UIUserNotificationSetting for iPhone5 iOS 8.2 not showing the alert message

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am working on Local Notification, initial setup for the local notification the pop up alert message is not showing in iOS 8.2 below IPhone 5 simulator.

```
 UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

The default pop up message is not displaying  "Your App" would like to send you Notifications Notication may include alerts, sound and icon badges. These can be configured in settings.

Comment: pls add localnotification code

Comment: Its about application level popup message "The default pop up message is not displaying "Your App" would like to send you Notifications Notication may include alerts, sound and icon badges. These can be configured in settings".

Comment: try to first uninstall old application than install new

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265433/registerusernotificationsettings-not-showing-prompt-ios-8